# My Discord.js bot gets an error when trying to send DMs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, since yesterday my bot is unable to send DMs without receiving an error.
It actually sends the message to the user's DMs but it also receives this error with .catch:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Users\me\Discord\mybot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 50007,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

My bot doesn't seem to be blacklisted or anything similar that could cause this error.

This is the *synchronous* (might be the issue but I don't know how) code when the error occurs (I simplied it and removed a lot of things but I'm still getting 400 Bad request):

```
client.on('message', message => {
    message.member.user.send(message.content).catch(console.error);
})
```

I also tried `message.author.send` or `message.member.send`, same issue, I receive the DM and then the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't check if the message author is a robot.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    message.member.user.send(message.content).catch(console.error);
})
```

Therefore, after the bot sends you a message, the message you received in the DMs (from the bot) is detected by the `message` event and the bot tries to send a message to himself.

Fix:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false // Checking if the message author is a bot.
    message.member.user.send(message.content).catch(console.error);
})
```

Comment: Awww thanks. Thanks to you, I figured out there was an issue with my DB as the bot attempts to find guild id before sending the message, but DM channels are not supported by that. I just need to check that the message channel isn't DM. with that bit of code: `if (message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel) return;` so that it doesn't "backfires". thanks again ;D